# Nunit Ordering Issue with 2 classes in a project

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

I am trying to run Unit TestCases through Nunit where i have two Unit TestCase classes,
1 class which deals with Product Console 
2nd class which deals with other Windows processes and services, and both are under same project and they are set a sequence through Nunit Ordering which is very important aspect as all the testcases have to run sequentially.

When I am trying to run the testcases through command line, only the testcases specific to one class is running irrespective or ordering.

So, for example :

```
NoConsoleclass.cs

[Test , Order(1)]
public void Test1()
{}

[Test, Order(3)]
public void Test3()
{}

ConsoleTestCases.cs
[Test, Order(2)]
public void Test2()
{}

nunit3-console projectname.dll is running 1 and 3 first and then test 2.
```

Is there any way I could attain it the way I want as test 1, test 2 and then test 3??

I know, sequencing or pre-requisites is not adviceable, but it is required for this specific suite.

Kindly let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, no.

There's an open feature request to allow the ordering of different TestFixtures - see the link below.
https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/345

This still wouldn't cover your case however, of wanting to interleave tests from different classes in a specific order. (Although would, if you were able to break this up into three classes.)

There's also an open feature request for a TestDependencyAttribute - which would allow you to specify one test as being dependent on the completion of others. This perhaps seems close to what you want to represent, than actual explicit ordering. Find that one at the link below.
https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/51